# Theaded Console.Getkey() seems to requires multiple key presses to register the key that is pressed

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating a console application that shows simple animations with text.  I have a thread that waits for the user to press "Up Arrow", "Down Arrow" and "Enter/Carriage Return/Return".  It seems that the user must press any of these keys multiple times for the key to be registered, however sometimes the key is registered instantly.  I assume, as you would too; that this is a problem with my code.  I had a power failure last week and it wiped out part of my project, whilst rewriting my code this problem appeared.
I have tried using

```
if(Console.KeyAvailable == true && Console.Readkey().key == [one of the three keys])
```

to no avail.
I tried removing (Memory memory) from the class leaving it just

```
private static void GetKeyboardInput() {}
```

but this didn't seem to have any effect.  BTW, when I did that the thread was declared like this

```
Thread getkey = new Thread(GetKeyboardInput);
```

perhaps I am doing this part wrong?

Here is some of my code neutered for size...

```
// declare listener thread and start it. 
Thread GetKey = new Thread(() => GetKeyboardInput(memory));
GetKey.Start();
while (GetKey.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
{ Animate(memory); } // this is the text animation, ---> Menuitem <---
                     // the arrows move in and out from the menu item
```

Animate(memory); runs in the current tread, so it isn't the culprit, correct?

```
// This is the code that the thread runs
// Memory class contains all stored values for this program
private static void GetKeyboardInput(Memory memory)
{
    while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
        {
            // move up. There is more code here but not relevant
        }
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
        {
            // Move Down. Same as before
        }
    }
    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
}
```

I expect that in less than 1000ms after a key is pressed that the revelant code within the if statements gets executed and the screen will show a change to the user, if any.

Actual results are that sometimes the program reacts to user input instanly, and other times the user has to press the key multiple times to register a change.  This is not session dependent either, at any time during execution both of these above problems will/can be present.

Comment: You're reading the key multiple times. Once to check that it's not enter, again to check whether it's UpArrow, yet again to check whether it was DownArrow. You probably want to read it once, and store it in a variable.

Comment: This would be a decent question, but separating the technical parts of the question from your rambling thoughts (about how someone somewhere sometime in the past treated you in a way you felt was unfair) -- separating that is **your job as the asker** not ours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `Console.ReadKey()` multiple times: once to check that it's not enter, again to check whether it's UpArrow, yet again to check whether it was DownArrow. You probably want to read it once, and store it in a variable.

```
// This is the code that the thread runs
// Memory class contains all stored values for this program
private static void GetKeyboardInput(Memory memory)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
        if (key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
        {
            // move up. There is more code here but not relevant
            // meaning these values effect the animation and nothing else
        }
        else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
        {
            // Move Down. Same as before
        }
    }
    // No need to call Thread.Abort - exiting this method does the same
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't realize that you can end a thread with break.

Comment: It's isn't the break the ends the thread. The break breaks out of the loop. When execution leaves the loop, then it returns from "GetKeyboardInput". Since "GetKeyboardInput" is the method which is run by your thread, the thread exits when that method returns.

Comment: OK. I appreciate the clarification. Thanks again!